# Extendable Custom CardView does not display all content of RecyclerView from Firebase

Tags: android, xml, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm using CardView to create expandable item that displays Firebase information in it. I tested Firebase implementation and it worked fine, here is the screenshot:

[image: first image]

After i created Expandable CardView like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".campus">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Кампус" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/groupImage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_apartment"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groupName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/groupImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/groupImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/groupImage" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandableView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/groupImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/childRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/expandableView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/expandableView" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To make it expand i used this code:

```
expandableView = findViewById(R.id.expandableView);
        cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (expandableView.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new AutoTransition());
                    expandableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new AutoTransition());
                    expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

But it didn't worked properly. After expanding CardView it only displays one element of RecyclerView. Here is the screenshot of this:

[image: problem]

How can i make it to display all of the RecyclerView content? And is there any other ways to make it?

Answer (score 0):

1-> Reformat your cards so they fit within a reasonable screen size. This one will require you to tinker around with it based on your view and what you want to display, you could also cut it off with a `ellipsis` and have an `onClickListener` setup to display details on the card.

OR

2-> Add a `HorizontalScrollView` as the parent of the `RecyclerView`/`CardView` so you can scroll left and right.

```
<android.widget.HorizontalScrollView>
      <!-- your params here-->
      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                 <!-- your params here-->
      </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</android.widget.HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I thing you don't get my problem. I want to make CardView to expand and show all the context of the Recycler view, it has 2 child (as it shown in first screenshot) but inside Expandable CardView it only displays 1 child (second screenshot).